# JQuery hover and click event

Tags: jquery

I have a number of photos of people on a page and I want to display an alternate photo of a person on mouse over and have the photo revert to the default on mouse out. I also want the alternate photo to be displayed when someone clicks the photo to see their profile (which appears on the sidebar). The default photo will appear for that individual when someone clicks on a different person. I am having trouble combining click and hover events to achieve this.

Here is what I have so far. I'm party there, however this does not revert the previously viewed profile picture to it's default photo. How do I remove the click event from a previously viewed profile when a different profile picture is clicked?

```
    $('.rollover').click(function() {
        $(this).unbind('mouseout'); 
    }).mouseover(function() {
          img_src = $(this).attr('src'); //grab original image
          new_src = $(this).attr('rel'); //grab rollover image
          $(this).attr('src', new_src); //swap images
          $(this).attr('rel', img_src); //swap images
    }).mouseout(function() {
          $(this).attr('src', img_src); //swap images
          $(this).attr('rel', new_src); //swap images
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing and works just as I wanted. There may be a way to simplify this and I'd be open to suggestions. Thanks to those who replied.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//rollover swap images with rel 
  var img_src = "";
  var new_src = "";

$('.rollover').click(function() {

        if($(this).hasClass("clicked"))
    {
            //do nothing if this element has already been clicked
    }
    else 
    {   
        //Unbind the hover effect from this element
        $(this).removeClass("rollover");
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')

        //Go through and find anything having 'clicked' class -
        //in theory, there should only be one element that has the 'clicked' class at any given time.
        $('.clicked').each(function (){
                $(this).removeClass("clicked");
                $(this).addClass("rollover");

                //Swap the images
                img_src = $(this).attr('src'); //grab original image
                new_src = $(this).attr('rel'); //grab rollover image
                $(this).attr('src', new_src); //swap images
                $(this).attr('rel', img_src); //swap images

                //Rebind hover (since we unbound it back up there ^^) to this *specific* element.
                //If you do $(".rollover") to rebind, it kills all the other existing binds and binds ONLY this element.
                $(this).hover(function(){
                        img_src = $(this).attr('src'); //grab original image
                        new_src = $(this).attr('rel'); //grab rollover image
                        $(this).attr('src', new_src); //swap images
                        $(this).attr('rel', img_src); //swap images
                        });
                }); 

        $(this).addClass("clicked");

    } 
});

$(".rollover").hover(function(){
      img_src = $(this).attr('src'); //grab original image
      new_src = $(this).attr('rel'); //grab rollover image
      $(this).attr('src', new_src); //swap images
      $(this).attr('rel', img_src); //swap images
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a click handler by using the `on` method.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      img_src = $(this).attr('src'); 
      new_src = $(this).attr('rel'); 
      $(this).attr('src', new_src); 
      $(this).attr('rel', img_src); 
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
      $(this).attr('src', img_src); 
      $(this).attr('rel', new_src); 
    }, 
    click: function() {
     // ...
    },
}, ".rollover");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is missing the unbind event. I updated my question with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

The rel attribute is only for anchor and link tags. You should try an alternative. I have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8eMFp/1/). Let's see if this is what you are looking for.